# Estimating parameters GARCH model

Tags: estimation, least-squares, garch

Suppose I have the following model
\begin{equation}
    R_{i t}-r_{t}=\alpha_{i}+\beta_{i}\left(R_{m t}-r_{t}\right)+s_{i} S M B_{t}+h_{i} H M L_{t}+\varepsilon_{i t}
    \label{eqn:egarch}
\end{equation}
Where $\varepsilon_{i t} \sim \mathrm{N}\left(0, \sigma_{i t}^{2}\right)$
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
\ln \sigma_{i t}^{2}=a_{i}+\sum_{l=1}^{p} b_{i, l} \ln \sigma_{i, t-l}^{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{q} c_{i, k}\left\{\theta\left(\frac{\varepsilon_{i, t-k}}{\sigma_{i, t-k}}\right)\right. \\
\left.+\gamma\left[\left|\frac{\varepsilon_{i, t-k}}{\sigma_{i, t-k}}\right|-(2 / \pi)^{1 / 2}\right]\right\}\label{eqn:sig2}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
Suppose I only have the estimates of $\ln \sigma_{i t}^{2}$ and the data for variables $R_{i t}-r_{t}$,$R_{m t}-r_{t}$, $S M B_{t}$ and  $H M L_{t}$.

How do I now translate this information to the first linear model? So that I can estimate the parameters using OLS?

Comment: You already can estimate the model by OLS as you have the relevant data, but this is probably not what you want. Given estimates of $\ln\sigma_{it}^2$, you could estimate the first model by weighted least squares (WLS) with weights inversely proportional to $\hat\sigma_{it}$.

Comment: I think what you describe is what I want to do. However, I am a bit confused. Do I first estimate the errors $\varepsilon_{it}$ from OLS and then create $\ln\sigma_{it}^2$?.

Comment: You said you already have the estimates of $\ln\sigma_{it}^2$. If you do not, the entire model can be estimated using maximum likelihood. Hopefully there exist some packages or functions to do that, but none come to mind right away.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification